What's the error in 阵阵鞭炮声使我的心兴奋起来，我跑到窗前，看美丽的烟花已铺满了天空?

阵阵鞭炮声使我的心兴奋起来，我跑到窗前，看美丽的烟花已铺满了天空。
HSK6 Standard Course Workbook (下册, chapter 21, page 5; photo of question)

This is considered a 语病, although I originally thought it was fine.  I currently have multiple hypotheses as to where the fault lies:

看 should be 看着 or 看到.  Misusing 看 is a common 语病 question, but I don't think it's a problem here, since 看天空 functions like 看电视.

美丽 should be added directly before 天空, as in 看烟花已铺满了的美丽天空.  Otherwise there's ambiguity: does 美丽 describe 烟花 or 天空?

铺满 should be 布满.  I don't really have a strong argument for this, but it seems like 铺满 is a deliberate spreading out of something for display purposes.

We need to add a 被 before 烟花, as in 看美丽的被烟花已铺满了天空.

The 了 should be a 的, as in 看美丽的烟花已铺满的天空.

兴奋 cannot describe 心, as per an answer at this HiNative post:

“兴奋”是整个人的身体状态兴奋，不是只有“心”兴奋。

although I don't see any reason why someone's 心 cannot 兴奋起来.


Multiple of these reasons could be correct, or there might be other reasons I haven't thought of.  Currently, I'd probably prefer 看着被烟花已布满了的美丽天空, but my preference doesn't imply the original is somehow wrong.
Question: What's the error in 阵阵鞭炮声使我的心兴奋起来，我跑到窗前，看美丽的烟花已铺满了天空?

阵阵鞭炮声使我的心兴奋起来，我跑到窗前，看美丽的烟花已铺满了天空。
The keywords in this sentence are 已...了, which means the time of "美丽的烟花铺满天空" is earlier than the verbs (actions) 跑到 and 看. Therefore, it must be 看到.
I am unable to match the sentence to suitable English tenses.
I could provide some easier examples.
(1) 李明去医院看他的母亲了。
(2) 李明去医院, 看到他的母亲已经好转了很多。

while the exact equivalent sentence error may not exist in english, this type of error does, and equivalent of that would be like "I will go to the park and saw what happened there."

I would like to rewrite your example and believe it is perfectly ok for an English person. “I will go to the park tomorrow and see what happened there last week.”

the point of the example is to show an example of the grammatical error, rewriting it defeats the purpose.

There's multiple issues found in the sentence given. Although I can't exactly say that it is not understandable, I can say that it definitely isn't the best way to describe the scene. There's many ways to fix the sentence, but I'll only list three here.
Original sentence:

阵阵鞭炮声使我的心兴奋起来，我跑到窗前，看美丽的烟花已铺满了天空

Fixed version #1:

一阵阵鞭炮声使我兴奋起来，我跑到窗前，看着美丽的烟火佈滿天空

Fixed version #2:

一阵阵鞭炮声使我的心兴奋了起来，我跑到窗前，看着美丽的烟火已經佈满了天空

Fixed version #3 (the best of all, but considerably more words):

一阵又一阵的鞭炮声使我頗兴奋的，因此我跑到窗前，看到了美丽的烟火已經佈满天空

The errors int he original sentence can be summarized as follows:

"阵阵" used at the start of a sentence is a bit weird, although technically not incorrect (Chinese has a loose grammar). Simple way to fix this is to add the word "一" (one) at the front, which (somehow) makes this a lot much better. This is used in fixed versions #1 and #2. In #3, I used the longer but more natural "一阵又一阵".
"我的心兴奋起来" is also quite weird. Simplest way to fix is to add the "了" particle, as in correct version #2. In version #1, I changed it to "我兴奋起来", thus removing the two words "的心", which corrects this part. Finally, in #3, I used "我頗兴奋的" as a replacement. Although you may or may not have heard or seen of the word "頗" (Po, meaning "very", or "quite", a Classical Chinese phrase found in many 文言文 texts), it's actually quite commonly used, even in modern text. It's important to note here though that using "頗" is basically my preference and not necessarily the only correct replacement option here.
You're correct on the "看着" part, it's supposed to be either "看着" or "看到". I used "看着" in version #1 and #2, and "看到" in #3.
Also, "铺满" is incorrect. However, your alternative isn't completely correct either. It should be "佈滿" instead of "布满". "布" essentially means "cloth", while "佈" (with the "人" particle at the left) means "covered" or "spread".
Many prefer to use "烟火" instead of "烟花", but that's probably just my opinion.

As for the "美丽" (number 2) and "被" (number 4) parts, the original sentence is actually OK.

Any comment from downvoter?


看 should be 看到. "到" means the action "看" is achieved/completed. For ex.  - "我看到(一頭)牛(I see/saw a cow)" vs "我看牛(I watch/look at the cow)". (Note, 看着[kàn zhe] is an alternative to 看到. 看着 indicates the action is ongoing or the continuation of the action - looking/watching.)

美丽 can be used to describe both the fireworks and the sky, however, in this case, the sky is overshadowed by the 炫目的煙花, which is the focus topic.

I prefer "填滿" over "铺满" or "布满", but I wouldn't say they are wrong.

被 means "by". You can say "天空已被美麗的煙花填滿了".

The particle "了" indicates the completion of the action at the time of observation - 铺满. (铺满的 is an adjective that describes the noun/noun phrase after it - "被美麗的煙花填滿的天空".

Yes. You can say "阵阵鞭炮声使我(整個人)兴奋(了)起来,"



Re: "I prefer "填滿" over "铺满" or "布满"". 填滿 in this case is almost certainly incorrect. Sure, you did say that's it's your preference, but I figured that I should tell you anyway. 填滿 essentially means to fill something up, like "填滿那個坑" (fill in that pit), and in a way means to actually completely fill up something, which is not something you can do with the sky. >>>

(cont)>>> 布满, on the other hand, just means that something is spread over a large area, which is the case with the fireworks-sky relationship. Also, " but I wouldn't say they are wrong.": 布满 certainly is correct, but 铺满 is even more incorrect than 填滿.

@Admirerofthedragonflag "铺满" or "布满" has the sense that the sky is filled fully with fireworks. Similarly, "填滿" means the sky is filled with fireworks scattered/spread throughout. All the words mean "the sky is filled", but with different actions, AS noted, it is only a personal preference matter.

Whether it's  "铺满", "布满" or "填滿" 了天空,  my view is that the translation into English would be "the fireworks blanket the whole sky", (which implies spreading over a two-dimensional plane), rather than "fill", (which implies saturation of a three dimensional cavity)
